# Simulation of an AC-DC circuit

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, filter, bridge-rectifier, resistive-load

What causes the total harmonic distortions to increase while you increase the filter inductance of an AC-DC circuit with a resistive load and an output capacitor.

Comment: You need to draw a schematic and name the node used to measure THD.

Comment: Is this homework?